# Duplicate Cart Totals on Woocommerce Checkout Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

Trying to figure out why my cart totals, cart subtotals, shipping, and coupons are getting displayed twice on my checkout page:

[image: Duplicate cart totals]

The problematic contents of my review order page are as follows:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total' ); ?>
<div>
  <?php _e( 'Cart Subtotal: ', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
  <?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?><br>
  <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
    <?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?>
    <?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_custom( $coupon ); ?><br>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
    <?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?>&nbsp;
    <?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?><br>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php _e('Cart Total: ', 'woocommerce'); ?>
  <?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?>
</div>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total' ); ?>
```

If I delete all of the above, everything goes away. If I delete only some of the "totals", the remaining "totals" are the only ones that get duplicated. So I think there is something in my code that is causing the duplication but for the life of me I can't figure out what. And the weird thing is that I use the exact same code on the cart page but it doesn't get duplicated ?!?!?!?

I'd appreciate some prompt help on this matter as I have a deadline later today. Thanks guys for your assistance!

Comment: It sounds like you have an "out of date" WooCommerce template. If you're using the latest version of WooCommerce, but are using template logic that mirrors how things used to be in 2.3 or lower, this can happen. I recommend taking a look at the new WooCommerce templates for an example of how things should be done now.

Comment: @rnevius yes, this is actually a custom Woocommerce template in my theme folder. And the Woocommerce system status says all my overrides are up to date. Does that help or do you still recommend taking a look?

Comment: I would recommend disabling your template (and possibly testing against a default theme) to either confirm that is the issue or exclude it.

Comment: @helgatheviking I have done so and it is indeed some part of my theme that's causing the problem...

Comment: In my experience, there isn't a lot of reason to override some of the cart/checkout templates.

Answer (score 0):

Your duplicate could be coming from the either of the two do_action(s). Test by removing the do_action(s). Then go hunting for the add_action trigger.